# Is SQLite varchar(power-of-2) faster than other sizes?

Tags: string, performance, sqlite

Are SQLite varchar(power-of-2) generally more efficient?

I think it should be because of alignment with SIMD registers and thereby instructions BUT I´m not sure whether or not they are internally null terminated making power-of-2-minus-one the optimal choice. And even then maybe sqlite does not do anything of above mentioned...

Comment: Interesting question.  Can you also tell us where SQLite is running (e.g. a C program, an Android app, etc.) ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen In my case it is C/C++ program on a desktop system but for what i know SQLite is one and the same c-library on all platforms so it should not matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQLite's [on-disk file format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html), field values are not aligned.

[And](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity_name_examples):

> Note that numeric arguments in parentheses that following the type name (ex: "VARCHAR(255)") are ignored by SQLite.

Comment: Forgot to mention i´m running the db in memory (:memory:) so file format does not apply in my case. However the docs are pretty clear with 'numeric arguments in paranthesis ... are ignored'.

Comment: An in-memory database is a file cache that never actually writes to a file.